# Failed to load module script when importing a .jpg file in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, mime-types, mime

I'm just trying to import an image in a javascript file to test webpack assets.
When I start the Live Server extenssion in VS-Code, I should see the image but I receive following Error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/jpeg". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import tech2 from "./tech2.jpg";

function addImage() {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  img.alt = "Tech.";
  img.width = 300;
  img.src = tech2;
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  body.appendChild(img);
}

addImage();
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "none",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**There is nothing in the body!:**

[image: There is nothing in the body.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has features that can take an `import` pointing to an image file and convert it to a URL. Browsers can't do that, the only thing you can use `import` to load in a browser is a JavaScript module.

You have a Webpack config, but you aren't using it.

- You said you were using VS Code Live Server
- The url in the browser points to `src` not `dist` (so you aren't running the webpack build pipeline manually and using the results).

If you want to use Webpack while you develop, use [the Webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) instead of the VS Code Live Server extension.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've imported my jpg file in a javascript file and the type of file is defined as module. However there is an error. I also tried webpack dev server and still can not display my HTML file. Should I add my configuration for webpack dev server too?

Comment: If you have problems using the webpack dev server, then that's a *different* problem so you should ask a new question, provide a [mcve], and quote the full error message if there are any related to that approach.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. But my recent question is that should not the browser display my empty HTML with single javascript file which uses import method to add the jpg file? Does it require loader or the browser should be able to import the jpg file using javascript and add it to the body of HTML file?

Comment: @Codie — I refer you to the second sentence of this answer.

Comment: I've read it. But I'm following a course that instructor just copied the path of the index.html file and pasted it in a browser. And It displayed the image without any errors. because of that, I've been searching documents. However, I will ask another question about webpack and share my code and configuration there. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: You must have missed something the instructor did. Browsers can't import anything that isn't a JS module.